Separate server for development - cannot access
I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I have a server with an active website (actually two, via virtual hosting).  I want to have a second server, basically a mirror, where I can make changes, repairs, etc and test before going live.  Probably scp or something from the test site to the active site.  Both sites are Debian Linux (one is 10.6, the other is 12.7), running apache2.  The development system is not visible on the internet (port 80 forwards the main system).  Development work is done on a Win 10 system.  I have copied the main web tree from the active site (server7) to the development site (server5).  From the windows box I can enter //server7 in a browser and it finds and loads the site.  When I enter //server5 in the same browser, I get a "Forbidden" error.  Both servers are visible, pingable, etc.  Not sure what else I can say except that I need help.
I would expect to see the server5 site from my browser and editors.  Both instances of apache2 run under www-data, there may be some permisions differences for some individual files but most are owned by root:root.  Log file shows "client denied by server configuration /web/httpd/htdocs/" groups issue?

So what are the file permissions of that folder?

Most of the files are 755 or 744.  The interesting thing is that the active site has the same ownerships and permissions.  This has to be something pretty simple that I am overlooking.  Seems to me that all I need to do is copy the web tree from the active system to the dev system.  I used scp to make the copy.

What are the permissions of the folder ...

FOUND IT!  Started running diff on the config files for both systems and found one line (hey, only 1 line) denying access to "/".  Seems to be working now.  Thanks for playing, now on to the next thing...
